# Adding 0.0.0.0 to /etc/hosts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I see something like this in several Rails install guides. What exactly are we doing here?

Add default subdomain to /etc/hosts, for example:
"0.0.0.0 localhost.lan group1.localhost.lan group2.localhost.lan"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could either bind a domain/subdomain to localhost 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 to have an address which you can use in your browser to access your app.

When a service is listening on 0.0.0.0 this means the service is listening on all the configured network interfaces, when listening on 127.0.0.1 the service is only bound to the loopback interface (only available on the local machine).

So "0.0.0.0 localhost.lan group1.localhost.lan group2.localhost.lan" means "Please make the domains localhost.lan, group1.localhost.lan and group2.localhost.lan browsable and point them to all my network adapters".

Comment: That does not answer the question `What exactly are we doing here?`

Comment: Added that in an edit just as you added the comment. But gave you an upvote as you nailed that one first.

Answer (score 5):

It means **all the domains and its aliases** will point to **all the IP addresses** assigned to this machine.

So If you machine has 3 IP NIC and IP is assigned to each one. Then that line will point all the names to all of those 3 IPs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing an app which requires a valid subdomain, the rails guide talk about adding that subdomain to the hosts file. so that they can route that request to your localhost(127.0.0.1)

example:

```
127.0.0.1   sampleapp.heroku.com
```

Comment: That does not answer the question `What exactly are we doing here?`

Comment: similar to my example above, it means 0.0.0.0 will behave in the same manner. isn't it ?

Comment: It will behave the same as long as you don't have some more complicated network setup with a lot of interface running. In that case 0.0.0.0 might work better.